# Angular Masonry multi-column with percentage width

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-masonry, masonry

I have the following template (note I use [angular-masonry-directive](https://github.com/klederson/angular-masonry-directive)):

```
<div masonry='{ "transitionDuration" : "0.4s" , "itemSelector" : ".tile", "columnWidth":1}'>
    <div masonry-tile ng-repeat="item in queryset" class="tile">
        <item  ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'"></item>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works great when I specify the width of .odd and .even in pixels, e.g. 600px and 300px, but it does not when I use percentages, e.g. 60% and 30%. Is it even possible with Masonry? If not, what would you suggest? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add `percentPosition: true` to the masonry settings.  This tells Masonry to compute the width based on a percentage.

```
<div masonry='{ "transitionDuration" : "0.4s" , "itemSelector" : ".tile", 
"columnWidth":1, percentPosition: true}'>
    <div masonry-tile ng-repeat="item in queryset" class="tile">
        <item  ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'"></item>
    </div>
</div>
```

See more options here: [masonry.desandro.com/options.html](http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html)